# Cordova Local Notifications list not available

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Currently I have a Cordova app that uses katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.  The problem I'm having is that if I get multiple notifications, I'm only able to see the latest and not the full list of notifications for the past 24 hours.  Currently when you swipe from the top down on your iphone, you're able to see a full list of notifications from multiple sources.  With the way I have implemented things in my app I'm only able to see the latest notification of my cordova app.  Here's my code:

```
getNotification(time) {
        const url = this.url + '/notification?time=' + time;
        this.eventSource = new EventSource(url);

        this.eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
            var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            if (data[0]) {
                this.data = data[0].postId;


                cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule([
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        title: 'My App',
                        text: this.message
                    }
                ]);
            }
        };

        this.eventSource.onerror = (error) => console.log(error);
    }
```

I have the following relevant versions of libraries/frameworks:

```
"cordova-ios": "^4.5.4",
"cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
"cordova-plugin-local-notification": "git+https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git"
```

Cordova -v:  8

Comment: This is because you have set the id to 1. Every time when the notification is fired, it replaces existing id. Try using id increment.

Comment: Yep, you are right @Hoon.